# OpenCL not Updating OpenGL VBO

Tags: opengl, opencl

I'm taking the first step into OpenCL coding.  I have a framework that I know can at least take an array from the CPU, do an operation in OpenCL, then read back the array (with the right answer).  I'm currently trying to improve this by adding a displaced mesh as found in [this OpenCL example](http://sa09.idav.ucdavis.edu/docs/SA09_GL_interop.pdf) (slides 18-23; only significant improvement is I changed the VBO to a float3 instead of a float4).

I have set up a shared context as per earlier in those slides and [this resource](http://www.dyn-lab.com/articles/cl-gl.html).  I tested the VBO with CPU input data (so I know it draws correctly).  Also, I create the context before the VBO (as motivated by [this thread](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/159011)).  Finally, I tried reworking the kernel into the following [edited]:

```
__kernel void sine_wave(__global float3* pos, int width, int height, float time) {
    uint x = get_global_id(0); uint y = get_global_id(1);
    pos[y*width+x] = (float3)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
}
```

Yet, no matter what I do, I cannot get the OpenCL program to update anything.  There are no errors, nothing, yet the VBO remains the same as the input data.  If I do not specify input data, the points all render at (0,0,0).  I can't figure out what could cause this.

Ideas?  Thanks,
Ian

PS #1: current system is NVIDIA GTX 580M, on Windows 7 x64, though the code written is intended to be portable.

PS #2: I can provide code if no one has any clues . . .

Comment: I don't get it.. you said the only significant improvement you did is changing from float3 to float4, but from what i see, you totally changed the code from slide 20 into an obscure for loop inside a kernel

Comment: That kernel loop looks to contain a huge buffer overflow. It is also completely serial....

Comment: ardiyu07: Yes, I tried it both with the original code and with my reduced version to no effect.  @talonmies: okay, I didn't understand what get_global_id was.  I think I understand better now.  And yes, the serial bit was intentional; I wanted to force everything to be one so I could see *something* change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  After further hours of searching, I downloaded NVIDIA's GPU computing toolkit, which appears to be where the linked demo derives from.  I then reduced their code down immensely to the following ~220 line source (may it help ye future coders):

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"OpenCL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")

// OpenGL Graphics Includes
#include <GL/glew.h>
#if defined (__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
    #include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
    #include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
    #include <GL/glut.h>
    #ifdef UNIX
        #include <GL/glx.h>
    #endif
#endif

#include <CL/opencl.h>

// Rendering window vars
const unsigned int window_width = 512;
const unsigned int window_height = 512;
const unsigned int mesh_width = 256;
const unsigned int mesh_height = 256;

// OpenCL vars
cl_context cxGPUContext;
cl_device_id* cdDevices;
cl_command_queue cqCommandQueue;
cl_kernel ckKernel;
cl_mem vbo_cl;
cl_program cpProgram;
size_t szGlobalWorkSize[] = {mesh_width, mesh_height};

// vbo variables
GLuint vbo;

int mouse_old_x, mouse_old_y;
int mouse_buttons = 0;
float rotate_x = 0.0, rotate_y = 0.0;
float translate_z = -3.0;
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        mouse_buttons |= 1<<button;
    } else if (state == GLUT_UP) {
        mouse_buttons = 0;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}
void motion(int x, int y) {
    float dx, dy;
    dx = (float)(x - mouse_old_x);
    dy = (float)(y - mouse_old_y);

    if (mouse_buttons & 1) {
        rotate_x += dy * 0.2f;
        rotate_y += dx * 0.2f;
    } else if (mouse_buttons & 4) {
        translate_z += dy * 0.01f;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

void DisplayGL(void) {
    static float anim = 0.0f;

    // run OpenCL kernel to generate vertex positions
    glFinish();
    clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(cqCommandQueue, 1, &vbo_cl, 0,0,0);

    clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 3, sizeof(float), &anim);
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cqCommandQueue, ckKernel, 2, NULL, szGlobalWorkSize, NULL, 0,0,0 );

    clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects(cqCommandQueue, 1, &vbo_cl, 0,0,0);
    clFinish(cqCommandQueue);

    // set view matrix
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, translate_z);
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mesh_width * mesh_height);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    // flip backbuffer to screen
    glutSwapBuffers();

    anim += 0.01f;
}

void timerEvent(int value) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timerEvent,0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)/2 - window_width/2,  glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT)/2 - window_height/2);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenCL/GL Interop (VBO)");

    glutDisplayFunc(DisplayGL);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutTimerFunc(10, timerEvent,0);

    glewInit();

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)window_width / (GLfloat) window_height, 0.1, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Get the NVIDIA platform
    cl_platform_id cpPlatform;
    clGetPlatformIDs(1,&cpPlatform,NULL);

    // Get the number of GPU devices available to the platform
    cl_uint uiDevCount;
    clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &uiDevCount);

    // Create the device list
    cdDevices = new cl_device_id [uiDevCount];
    clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, uiDevCount, cdDevices, NULL);
    // Define OS-specific context properties and create the OpenCL context
#if defined (__APPLE__)
    CGLContextObj kCGLContext = CGLGetCurrentContext();
    CGLShareGroupObj kCGLShareGroup = CGLGetShareGroup(kCGLContext);
    cl_context_properties props[] = 
    {
        CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE, (cl_context_properties)kCGLShareGroup, 
        0 
    };
    cxGPUContext = clCreateContext(props, 0,0, NULL, NULL, &ciErrNum);
#else
#ifdef UNIX
    cl_context_properties props[] = 
    {
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentContext(), 
        CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentDisplay(), 
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)cpPlatform, 
        0
    };
    cxGPUContext = clCreateContext(props, 1, &cdDevices[uiDeviceUsed], NULL, NULL, &ciErrNum);
#else // Win32
    cl_context_properties props[] = 
    {
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(), 
        CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(), 
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)cpPlatform, 
        0
    };
    cxGPUContext = clCreateContext(props, 1, &cdDevices[0], NULL, NULL, NULL);
#endif
#endif

    // create a command-queue
    cqCommandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(cxGPUContext, cdDevices[0], 0, NULL);

    const char* cSourceCL = "__kernel void sine_wave(__global float4* pos, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float time)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   unsigned int x = get_global_id(0);\n"
    "   unsigned int y = get_global_id(1);\n"
    "\n"
    "   // calculate uv coordinates\n"
    "   float u = x / (float) width;\n"
    "   float v = y / (float) height;\n"
    "   u = u*2.0f - 1.0f;\n"
    "   v = v*2.0f - 1.0f;\n"
    "\n"
    "   // calculate simple sine wave pattern\n"
    "   float freq = 4.0f;\n"
    "   float w = sin(u*freq + time) * cos(v*freq + time) * 0.5f;\n"
    "\n"
    "   // write output vertex\n"
    "   pos[y*width+x] = (float4)(u, w, v, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n";
    cpProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource(cxGPUContext, 1, (const char **) &cSourceCL, NULL, NULL);

    clBuildProgram(cpProgram, 0, NULL, "-cl-fast-relaxed-math", NULL, NULL);

    // create the kernel
    ckKernel = clCreateKernel(cpProgram, "sine_wave", NULL);

    // create VBO (if using standard GL or CL-GL interop), otherwise create Cl buffer
    unsigned int size = mesh_width * mesh_height * 4 * sizeof(float);

    glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
    // initialize buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // create OpenCL buffer from GL VBO
    vbo_cl = clCreateFromGLBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, vbo, NULL);

    // set the args values 
    clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &vbo_cl);
    clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 1, sizeof(unsigned int), &mesh_width);
    clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 2, sizeof(unsigned int), &mesh_height);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

After comparison with my original code, I (eventually) found the key difference.

Right:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(context->command_queue, kernel->kernel, 2, NULL, global,NULL, 0,0,0 );
```

Wrong:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(context->command_queue, kernel->kernel, 2, NULL, global,local, 0,0,0 );
```

It turns out that the grid size I was using, 10x10, was smaller than the examples I had seen elsewhere, which told me to use 16x16 for "local".  Because "global" is the grid size, "global" was *smaller* than "local".

For some reason this didn't cause any errors, though at this point I honestly can't say I understand these variables' purposes completely.

Ian

Comment: You could have saved yourself a huge amount of pain if you included error checking in the code. The OpenCL API calls return a status (for example [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html)). If you checked that return value, it would have been immediately obvious that the kernel launch was failing and in the process narrowed down the scope of the hunt for the problem.

Comment: Ironically, I was *thoroughly* checking for errors in the code that I had written, but it still wasn't working as expected.  The problem was that I subsequently tried copying over the mesh example again, this time more verbatim from the source--which didn't include error checking.  Of course, when running the code with error checking, you'll get CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.